# Testing application with self signed cert - works with ubuntu 20.04 but not 18.04

Tags: openssl, certificates, tls

Using the below conf file to generate a self signed cert for testing purposes. I added the generated cert and pem as a tls certificate in the ingress and everything works perfectly with ubuntu 20.04 when running this command `curl --cacert key.crt https://<redacted>.com` When using ubuntu 18.04 with the same curl command, I get `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. Doesn't matter if it's u18 vm or docker image, same result. What am I missing?

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 730 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out key.crt -config req.conf -extensions 'v3_req'
```

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = <redacted>
ST = <redacted>
L = <redacted>
O = <redacted>
OU = <redacted>
CN = *.<redacted>.com
[v3_req]
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = <redacted>.com
DNS.2 = <redacted>.com
```

Comment: Technically speaking, a self-signed certificate is going to complain on cURL with any OS version.  This is why self-signed certificates are not trusted.  Have you verified you're using the exact same cURL command and settings in cURL on both systems?

Comment: 18.04 and 20.04. Using curl --cacert key.crt https://<redacted>.com

Comment: corrected the title